# main() in Go not running after C import

Tags: c, go, cgo

I am trying to import some C code for use in my Golang application. I am really new to Go so I most likely have done something stupid here:

I have one file `main.go` in the main directory and `yolo.go` in the `/yolo` subdirectory along with all my C code.

**yolo.go**

```
package yolo

import "C"

func Vals() string {
    return "Good to go!"
}
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "./yolo"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf(yolo.Vals())
    fmt.Printf("test")
}
```

This seems to compile fine - but none of the code in the `main()` function in `main.go` runs - no output is given, but no errors are either. If I forget about the `import "C"` everything runs just fine and I get the output I expect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried the same on  my machine `go version go1.7.3 linux/amd64` .It is working fine

Comment: I just tried on `go version go1.7.4 darwin/amd64`, no issues either. What does running `go env` output in your terminal?

Comment: Do not use relative import paths. It's not necessarily the problem here, but it's not supported in all cases by the guild tools.

Comment: @JimB - what would you recommend I use other than relative paths?

Comment: I'm assuming that somehow the specific C code that I am importing is causing the issue (I am importing the darknet YOLO Real Time Object Detection framework)

Comment: @abagshaw: an import path should always be relative to `$GOPATH/src`, or a `vendor/` directory in your project. See [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)